# Servlet throwing exception

Tags: exception

My servlet is throwing following exception, even though the required jar is placed in webcontent/lib.
Any solution for this?

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl

Comment: Is oracle jdbc driver in your classpath.

Comment: yes it is..i added in classpath also..

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054105/url-string-format-for-connecting-to-oracle-database-with-jdbc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054105/url-string-format-for-connecting-to-oracle-database-with-jdbc)

Comment: It's working after adding

Class.forName("");

Though I'm using JDBC 4.0.