# ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

This is my first trial application in Hibernate
I am getting following error

> ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
>   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1363)
>       at com.model.HibernetTest.main(HibernetTest.java:24)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
>       at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:703)
>       at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
>       at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:192)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:278)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
>       ... 5 more

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sample</property>
    <property name="hinernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="com.model.Student" resource="com/model/Student.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

I have added odbc jar in my classpath but still I am getting error saying Driver not found. I tried following JDBC connection class and it works great.

```
public class OracleJDBCExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

    System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

    Connection connection = null;

    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "sample", "root");

        PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement("select * from Employee");
        System.out.println("*******");
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("--->"+rs.toString());
        if(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("---> "+rs.getString(1));
        }
        rs.close();
        ps.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }

}
```

}

Please help me understand what is wrong with the code?

Comment: the answer of @Pops for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054105/url-string-format-for-connecting-to-oracle-database-with-jdbc may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As looks by code is nothing wrong but your **odbc.jar** is not found in your application server as i think. Can you tell which server you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [Oracle's JDBC driver](http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/11204/ojdbc6.jar)  and add it to your CLASSPATH env variable