# Not able to connect spring jpa with Oracle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hi I am using below configuration still I am getting error.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin@sca00tof.us.dell.com:1521:mfg1229
spring.datasource.username=apps
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=Oracle12cDialect
```

below dependency i used in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
             <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
```

still I am getting below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : Oracle12cDialect
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Clas?s.forName(Class.java:427) ~[na:na]
    enter code here

    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

WHat is the problem in my configuration. instead of `driver-class` i also checked with `driver-class-name`
I checked `OracleDialect`, `Oracle10gDialect` and `Oracle12cDialect` . for all the 3 i am getting same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is nothing like "Oracle12cDialect" dialect. you need to write in proper way. :--

in your property file it is:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=Oracle12cDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin@sca00tof.us.dell.com:1521:mfg1229
```

but it should be:--

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin@//sca00tof.us.dell.com:1521/mfg1229
```

if does not work then please change to:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Comment: Thank you so much.your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: I'm glad that my answer helped you

Answer (score 2):

The dialect for Oracle12c can be use with hibernate 5.x.

You should add this to your classpath:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.24.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Please note that you need the dialect for the coreesponding Version of Oracle DB.

How ever I can't see the exact framework you are using. Please check that the obove dependency is part of your classpath. This may come with other dependencies such as JPA oder spring-data.

---

Also please note that your jdbc string seems to be wrong.

It should look like this:

```
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@sca00tof.us.dell.com:1521:mfg1229"
```

See here for details: [URL string format for connecting to Oracle database with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054105/url-string-format-for-connecting-to-oracle-database-with-jdbc)

Comment: Thank you. actually it is giving same error. is ther any problem in db url? first line error is :java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:oracle:thin@sca00tof.us.oracle.com:1521:mfg1229

Comment: Iv''e edited my answer. Your are missing a ":" after thin.

Comment: Thank you so much Marcinek. That small mistake could have unnoticed and I would have struggled a lot. thanks for highlighting and helping me.